# How to move schema to other tablespace

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, database-schema, tablespace

Postgres 13.2 database contains schema named company2 which contains tables and indexes and is located in g:\Program Files\Postgresql\13\data directory.

Server has also drive I:

How to move tables and indexes from company2 schema to I: drive ?

Using

PostgreSQL 13.2, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit

on windows server.

Comment: 1) Read the docs [CREATE TABLESPACE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtablespace.html), then [Alter table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) and [Alter index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) 2) The schema can't be moved as they are not tied to a tablespace.

Comment: A schema is just a namespace, not something physical that can be moved.

Comment: Foreign data wrappers allow bulk import of schemas with everything in them, privilege system allows bulk grant/revoke for entire schemas and everything in them, drop can cascade to everything in a schema. By extension, it's sort of reasonable to expect a bulk tablespace switch operation - unfortunately, there isn't one. You'll have to run some dynamic sql `execute`  in a pl/pgsql loop over system catalogs to issue `alter...set tablespace` for everything inside, individually.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? And please, upgrade to 13.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to run some [dynamic sql `execute`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN)  in a pl/pgsql loop over [system catalogs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) to issue [`alter...set tablespace`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) for everything inside, individually. For example, tables are in `pg_tables`: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/CG3rah15)

```
select * from pg_tables where schemaname='company2';

do $do_block$
declare record_ record;
begin
for record_ in select schemaname,tablename from pg_tables 
               where coalesce(tablespace,'')<>'new_tablespace'
               and schemaname='company2'
  loop
  execute format ('alter table %I.%I set tablespace new_tablespace',record_.schemaname,record_.tablename);
end loop;
end $do_block$;

select * from pg_tables where schemaname='company2';
```

| schemaname | tablename | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company2 | test | postgres | *null* | t | f | f | f |

| schemaname | tablename | tableowner | tablespace | hasindexes | hasrules | hastriggers | rowsecurity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| company2 | test | postgres | new_tablespace | t | f | f | f |

Foreign data wrappers allow bulk import of schemas with everything in them, privilege system allows bulk grant/revoke for entire schemas and everything in them, drop can cascade to everything in a schema. By extension, it's sort of reasonable to expect a bulk tablespace switch operation - unfortunately, there isn't one.